# почему дает ошибку при запуске файла Empire (tool)

Tags: консоль, type-error

```
терминал Kali Linux tool Empire 
 народ подскажите что сделать все правильно писал ./empire 
File "/opt/Empire/./empire", line 35
    print '[*] Fresh start in docker, running reset.sh for you'
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
дает такую ошибку
```

Comment: Выглядит так, как будто вы запускаете через `Python 3` скрипт, написанный на `Python 2`. Хотя про `Python` в вопросе ни слова, но выглядит именно так.

Comment: у меня версия Python 3.11.1

Comment: @Anonymous , так поставите Python 2.7 и им запускаете, какие проблемы?

Comment: @АнонимныйПаша Не, эта тулза требует свежий питон, так не получится )  Тут наоборот наверное скрипт надо править

Comment: @Anonymous Так а скрипт этот кто писал, который запускается, откуда он? В третьем питоне `print` - это функция, у него скобки должны быть, как и написано в ошибке.

Comment: @CrazyElf может это и за версии питона но да там дает ошибку ./empire чтобы запустит инструмент как еще можно писать? чтобы запустить ?

Comment: Так это от тулзы готовый файл или вы его сами откуда-то взяли или что-то там меняли? Версия самого этого `empire` свежая? Для начала можете попробовать там поменять `print '[*] Fresh start in docker, running reset.sh for you'` на `print('[*] Fresh start in docker, running reset.sh for you')`

Comment: @CrazyElf сегодня сказал с git huba установил скачал setup все как по инструкции но дает ошибку когда хочу запустить этот инструмент

Comment: @Anonymous Ну похоже вы скачали версию для `Python 2`. Надо найти и скачать версию для `Python 3`. Так будет проще всего.

Comment: @CrazyElf трудно будет найти но да по ходу надо для python3 найти ;)